# Pymol gives seg-fault if and only if called from bash script

Tags: bash, pymol

So, I am writing a code to load and align two different pdb files into pymol, then save parts from each. I will need to run it on several different files. Unfortunately, when I try to start pymol from a bash script, it seg-faults. It even seg-faults if I only tell it to start pymol, which never happens when I start pymol from command line (manually typed). Why is this happening, how do I fix or get around the seg-fault issue?

I tried reducing the bash script to only call pymol to identify where the problem was, it still gives the seg-fault core dumped error

Edit: to clarify, align.sh is the script that is right below that only calls pymol

```
#!/bin/bash
pymol
#run align2.py
#aligning x147new.pdb, c2pucker.pdb
```

```
./align.sh: line 2: 21815 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) pymol
```

Comment: I don't see ./align.sh being called.

Comment: I guess `./align.sh` is the call to the script that contains the code he posted above. You can take a look over the core dump, it seems like a good start.

Comment: @Roadowl, hopefully that is clearer, danlor was correct.

Comment: @danlor, what do you mean by taking a look over the core dump? Is there some kind of log left when that happens?

Comment: Depends on your current configuration, though, it should. Look for a file called something like `core.pid`. You can `cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` in order to check the actual naming scheme/ path. For further information check out https://jvns.ca/blog/2018/04/28/debugging-a-segfault-on-linux/

Answer (score 1):

Manually install some dependencies should fix the problem:

```sh
sudo apt-get install git build-essential python3-dev libglew-dev \
libpng-dev libfreetype6-dev libxml2-dev \
libmsgpack-dev python3-pyqt5.qtopengl libglm-dev libnetcdf-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help danlor, looks like there are other issues on that machine related to corruption from the (unfortunately rather defunct) anaconda download of pymol (as soon as I downloaded Schrodingers so to try and figure out a python script to avoid both command line and the GUI while getting the results, nothing in pymol would work). As soon as I rebooted, it crashes from command line as well, just like from the script. As a side-note, if anybody can help me find another place that pymol files may be hiding so I can get a clean install, that would be most helpful.